# Set view content directly instead of using a template

Tags: zend-framework2, wkhtmltopdf

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to set the content of a view without using a template in Zend Framework 2. I have users creating emails in ckeditor, storing in text files, then grabbing the file contents and trying to produce a pdf for printing. Here's what is going on in the controller:

```
$emails = $this -> email() -> getEmails();

//Render the display
$viewRender = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
$view->setTemplate('module/controller/template.phtml');
$html = $viewRender->render($view);

//Create the HTML to PDF class instance & set the bin path
$wkpdf = new WkHtmlToPdf(array('bin'=>'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf'));

//Add it to the PDF
$wkpdf->addPage($html);

//Send it to the client
$wkpdf->send();
```

I want to replace the setTemplate() method with something that will directly set the view's content with the html string I have retrieved from the email files. Any thoughts?

This is what I came up with:

```
 $emails = $this -> email() -> getEmails();

 $email = $emails->$email_name;

 //Create the HTML to PDF class instance & set the bin path
 $wkpdf = new \WkHtmlToPdf(array('bin'=>$this->settings()->getSettings()->wkhtmltopdf_path));

 //Add the email to the PDF
 $wkpdf->addPage("<html>".$email."</html>");

 //Send it to the client
 $wkpdf->send();
```

All I needed to do was wrap the string with html tags for WkHtmlToPdf to process it.

Answer (score 0):

In your action, before returning content to your view file,

```
  $result = new ViewModel(array('view_contant_variable' => $content_to_assign));
  $result->setTerminal(true);
  return $result;
```

I hope this, may help to you to display your view file without template contents.